# Dynamically define singleton method on class that evaluates properly with subclass

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm currently working on a Minitest extension that wraps `Minitest::Runnable.run` with before/after_suite callbacks. The way that Minitest works is that test classes inherit from `Minitest::Runnable`. Also, `describe` blocks dynamically create classes which inherit from the test class they're defined in. So

```
# Minitest::Spec inherits from Minitest::Runnable
class TestClass < Minitest::Spec
  describe 'a describe block' do
    it 'should say hi' do
      # test here
    end
  end
end
```

Generates a new class that inherits from TestClass whose `name` is `"a describe block"`. This winds up going down the Minitest pipeline and calls `Mintest::Runnable.run` on each class (e.g. `self` in each case winds up being each of the classes including `"a describe block"`). For reference:

```
module Minitest::Runnable
  def self.run reporter, options = {}
    require 'rubygems'; require 'pry'; binding.pry
    filter = options[:filter] || '/./'
    filter = Regexp.new $1 if filter =~ /\/(.*)\//

    filtered_methods = self.runnable_methods.find_all { |m|
      filter === m || filter === "#{self}##{m}"
    }

    with_info_handler reporter do
      filtered_methods.each do |method_name|
        run_one_method self, method_name, reporter
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My extension is designed to work by allowing you to have a `before_suite` method which wraps Minitest::Runnable.run:

```
class TestClass < Minitest::Spec
  before_suite do
    # do something
  end

  describe 'a describe block' do
    it 'should say hi' do
      # test here
    end
  end
end
```

I've got it mostly working, however I'm running into an issue with inheritance. When I redefine the wrapper method, the receiver of my new singleton method winds up being `TestClass` even for subclasses (e.g. even for the descibe block). This causes my tests to not be found.

Below is my current implementation of before suite:

```
module Minitest::SuiteCallbacks
  def self.extended(base)
    base.class_eval do
      class << self
        def before_suite(&before_suite_proc)
          @before_suite_proc = before_suite_proc

          context = self
          original_singleton_run = method(:run)
          define_singleton_method :run do |*args, &block|
            # `self` here winds up being `TestClass` instead of the dynamic class
            # (e.g. self.name => "TestClass" instead of "a describe block")

            context.setup_before_suite
            original_singleton_run.call(*args, &block)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This grabs the current implementation of `run` and wraps it. The issue is that when it's called from the context of the dynamic `"a describe block"` subclass that `self` inside of the method is `TestClass` instead of the dynamic class.

Any thoughts on what I could do to remedy the issue? My goal is to be able to dynamically wrap any method in an inheritance chain and have it work properly with all of the child classes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The bug was with the method binding. I either had to `unbind` the method or open up the singleton class and get reference to the `UnboundMethod` via `instance_method`:

```
def before_suite
  # ...
  original = instance_method(:run)
  class << self
    define_method :run do |*args, &block|
      # add decorated logic
      original.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

This was my initial guess, but the error was coming from further down the stack (I wrap the run method again with after_suite and forgot to change that implementation). When in doubt, comment it out!